# Какой функционал есть у Visual Studio для разработки игр на Unity3d?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity3d

Какой функционал есть у Visual Studio которого нет в MonoDevelop, Xamarin Studio или VS Code для разработки игр на Unity3d?

Comment: лучше использовать ту среду, к которой привыкли и/или которая используется в компании, где Вы работаете.

Comment: У меня в монодевелопе комбинации раскладки клавиатуры забитые на ctrl+alt, не работают. Поэтому пользуюсь VS.

Comment: непонятно, что значит `но есть ли у неё функционал именно для Unity3d` ..... есть VS Tools for unity, который уже вшит в новые версии юнити (ну или скачать можно) и спокойно разрабатывается на VS и решарпером (можно и без него).... какой вам функционал нужен-то?

Comment: Дело не в том какой функционал нужен мне, а в том что может VS такого чего не могут другие.)

Comment: Дык а чё там уметь. Обычное IDE с подсветкой синтаксиса C#  и дебаггером. Сама за вас код писать точно не будет :D

Comment: Ну дык для того собственно вопрос и задавал, простой блокнот это, аль может есть киллер фичи :D

Comment: Смотря что имеется в виду под киллер фичами. Для древнего человека и зажигалка - фича. А сейчас - обыденность. Может для вас пушить в гит из IDE - фича, а может обыденность. Никто ж не в курсе)

Comment: Как это никто не в курсе!))) Я написал что обыденность это MonoDevelop, Xamarin Studio и VS Code. В любом случае никто не написал «Та ты чё VS может то-то-то, и это используют каждый день, а МоноДев вообще дно, у него дебагер через раз работает», поэтому буду считать своё любопытство удовлетворенным, а вас благодарю за беседу!

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, нативные среды разработки всегда будут лучше чем какие-то сторонние. К тому же выполнять свой код Вы будите в среде unity3d, а как редактор кода VS самый лучший вариант. ИМХО

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, возможно вам есть что добавить. Спасибо!

Comment: Как уже ответили выше, существует дополнительный пакет с инструментами разработчика для Unity, но если вы привыкли работать где-то еще, то можете остаться там где и хотели, но если ваша IDE не подходит, то я склоняюсь именно к VS

Answer (score 1):

Кому что удобней.  Visual Studio - больше функционал(намного), но у  MonoDevelop есть подсветка шейдеров.
Visual Studio - если ранее пользовался ей, то лучше ее и оставить, потому что  MonoDevelop, мне показался слишком сухим и не привычным.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984392/can-you-recomment-a-better-ide-for-unity-c-sharp-coding

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, возможно вам есть что добавить. Спасибо!

Comment: @Ihor Dziuba  Если у тебя нет винды, то только ради IDE ее ставить наверное не стоит.  Долго ты IDE  выбираешь, уже можно было сделать игру,  не парся так!

Comment: Да ладно всего-то пара часов прошло.) Я сам из веба. Когда начинал использовал года 2 Sublime Text и несколько сторонних прог, потом мне попался RubyMine и я понял что мучался всё это время, тут тебе и отладчик и терминал и работа с базой и гит и еще куча всего. Вот и возник вопрос, а не принять ли привинтивные меры и не узнать ли всё. Может быть в VS есть кнопка «сделать класную игру», а я буду мучаться, как дурак, и писать код в монодев.)))